# discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: ctx is a required argument that is missing

Tags: python, бот, discord

```
    @bot.command(name="ping")
async def ping(self, ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send(f"{bot.latency}")
```

что не так? Если я напишу client вместо bot мне вылетит ошибка

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'client' is not defined
```

а если я впишу bot -

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: ctx is a required argument that is missing.
```

Answer (score 0):

во-первых @bot.command() пишем без отступов, во-вторых зачем тебе аргумент self? ты можешь оставить только ctx и также можно убрать команду channel и оставить ctx.send()

Comment: спасибо за помощь <3